# using locals() inside dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

The following code doesn't work, I assume because the locals() variable inside the comprehension will refer to the nested block where comprehension is evaluated:

```
def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    list_ = ['a', 'b']
    dict_ = {x : locals()[x] for x in list_}
```

I could use `globals()` instead, and it seems to work, but that may come with some additional problems (e.g., if there was a variable from a surrounding scope that happens to have the same name).

Is there anything that would make the dictionary using the variables precisely in the scope of function `f`?

Note: I am doing this because I have many variables that I'd like to put in a dictionary later, but don't want to complicate the code by writing `dict_['a']` instead of `a` in the meantime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could perhaps do this:

```
def f(): 
    a = 1 
    b = 2 
    list_ = ['a', 'b'] 
    locals_ = locals()
    dict_ = dict((x, locals_[x]) for x in list_)
```

However, I would strongly discourage the use of `locals()` for this purpose.

Comment: I didn't think of this! And why is it bad to use locals() like this? I'm not using anything undocumented, am I?

Comment: It's not undocumented, but the use of `locals()` may trigger the compiler to generate less-than-optimal code for the function where it is referenced. For example, if the compiler determines that it can optimise out the use of some temporary variable (perhaps some *other* variable in the function unrelated to your dictionary), it might not be able to do that if `locals()` is used within the function. Also, by avoiding creating a dictionary first you're repeating yourself with (1) the assignment of each variable, and (2) the names in the list.

Comment: Then I am stuck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067463/alternative-to-locals-in-printing-a-table-with-a-header

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you're right: the `locals()` inside the dict comprehension will refer to the comprehension's namespace.

One possible solution (if it hasn't already occurred to you):

```
f_locals = locals()
dict_ = {x : f_locals[x] for x in list_}
```