# Alternative to locals() in printing a table with a header

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, locals

**[Python 3.1]**

Edit: mistake in the original code.

I need to print a table. The first row should be a header, which consists of column names separated by tabs. The following rows should contain the data (also tab-separated).

To clarify, let's say I have columns "speed", "power", "weight". I originally wrote the following code, with the help from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065976/using-locals-inside-dictionary-comprehension) I asked earlier:

```
column_names = ['speed', 'power', 'weight']

def f(row_number):
  # some calculations here to populate variables speed, power, weight
  # e.g., power = retrieve_avg_power(row_number) * 2.5
  # e.g., speed = math.sqrt(power) / 2
  # etc.
  locals_ = locals()
  return {x : locals_[x] for x in column_names}

def print_table(rows):
  print(*column_names, sep = '\t')
  for row_number in range(rows):
    row = f(row_number)
    print(*[row[x] for x in component_names], sep = '\t')
```

But then I learned that I should [avoid using `locals()` if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065976/using-locals-inside-dictionary-comprehension/4065991#4065991).

Now I'm stuck. I don't want to type the list of all the column names more than once. I don't want to rely on the fact that every dictionary I create inside `f()` is likely to iterate through its keys in the same order. And I don't want to use `locals()`.

Note that the functions `print_table()` and `f()` do a lot of other stuff; so I have to keep them separate.

How should I write the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Columns:
    pass

def f(row_number):
    c = Columns()
    c.power = retrieve_avg_power(row_number) * 2.5
    c.speed = math.sqrt(power) / 2
    return c.__dict__
```

This also lets you specify which of the variables are meant as columns, instead of rather being temporary in the function.

Comment: Would this be essentially identical to creating a dictionary `columns = {}`, and populating it like this: `columns['speed'] = math.sqrt(columns['power'])/2`?

Comment: And btw, is using `__dict__` any less of a problem for optimizers than using `locals()`?

Comment: Exactly so, except that I find the attribute syntax easier to read and type.

Comment: Storing into an object is much more expensive than storing into a local variable. So you shouldn't assign to c.power in a loop. However, since you eventually need to store the values all in a dictionary, there is no cost involved. The problem to optimizers is this: if locals() is used, they also need to stop using efficient access to local variables (so that they actually become slower than instance attributes).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to fix the order of the dictionaries. But as I see it that isn't even necessary. You are always taking the keys from the `column_names` list (except in the last line, I assume that is a typo), so the order of the values will always be the same.

Comment: I think It's hard to populate an `OrderedDict` without `locals()` and without repeating the names. (Also, note that the order I calculate the variables in, isn't necessarily the same as the column order required in the output table.)

Comment: @max: Ok, now I understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to locals() will be to use  the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module

```
import inspect

def f(row_number):
    # some calculations here to populate variables speed, power, weight
    # e.g., power = retrieve_avg_power(row_number) * 2.5
    # e.g., speed = math.sqrt(power) / 2
    # etc.
    locals_ = inspect.currentframe().f_locals
    return {x : locals_[x] for x in column_names }
```